# i have 500mb available but can't install 2mb app!

Tags: applications, ram

i have 500mb available but can't install 2mb app!!!
it's so frustrating i tried uninstalling apps, clearing cache, deleting files ... nothing works.

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your question, what app are you trying to install, what is 500MB? Amount of RAM? Free internal memory? Free external memory? What is your phone model?

Comment: 500 mb is 500 millibit, that's half a bit, and it's insufficient for anything. You probably mean 500 MB (capital "B" is for bytes, lowercase "b" is bits).

Comment: Look like most people here are too young to remember how many things can be done with 500MB. The answer is simple: Google got evil, and want you to throw away your smartphone and buy a new, more expensive one. Now they are friends of the smartphone companies, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Android will leave some space empty for own usage, normally by clearing cache or unistalling apps you should be able to install that app.
Here that isn't the case.
What I would try would be to get rid of some apps try clean master from tge google play store.
Worst case Factory data reset it or wipe the data off of it.