# Cannot install ip webcam app on Nexus 6p

Tags: 8.1-oreo, nexus-6p, webcam

I'm trying to re-purpose my Nexus 6p as a webcam. I wanted to install ip webcam on it, but the app store is is telling me that my device is not compatible. On the play store the ip webcam app listing states that Android 4.0 and up is the minimum required (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en). My Nexus 6p is running Android 8.1.0. It seems like it should be compatible and should be able to install ip webcam, but still it does not let me.

Any ideas why this might be and suggestions to try?

Comment: Try clearing space on your mobile by deleting big files or apps. [Less free space can prevent installation](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225262/131553) // Is this isn't the case try sideloading

Answer (score 0):

One thing I forgot to mention was this phone was stuck in a drawer for over a year. Ended up I had to update all of the apps in the play store and I guess some system app was also updated along the way. after that it installed fine.